# How can I convert a numerical field into a chr string of a specific format in R?

Tags: r, format

I have a column in my dataframe with numerical values up to 6 digits - e.g., 145, 137549, 2355, etc. - and I need to convert the data into a character string format that starts with "PV" and ends with 6 digits.  So, 145 -> "PV000145" and 137549 -> "PV137549" so the conversion is smart enough to add leading zeroes where needed.  How can I do this in R?

I tried the format function but can't figure out the correct inputs to add PV every time and still retain the number that is already in the field.

Answer (score 2):

```r
vec <- c(145, 137549, 2355)
sprintf("PV%06d", vec)
# [1] "PV000145" "PV137549" "PV002355"
```

`%06d` is a 0-padded (out to 6 digits) integer, see [`?sprintf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html) for that and other `%`-codes.

If your `vec` is already character (I'll convert the above for an example using `vec_chr <- as.character(vec)`), then we can use `stringr::str_pad` and `paste0`:

```r
paste0("PV", stringr::str_pad(vec_chr, 6, pad = "0"))
# [1] "PV000145" "PV137549" "PV002355"
```

or without `stringr` in another step or two:

```r
paste0("PV", strrep("0", max(nchar(vec_chr)) - nchar(vec_chr)), vec_chr)
# [1] "PV000145" "PV137549" "PV002355"
```

Comment: thank you, i can create the vector that converts the field but having trouble getting those values back into the original dataframe.  is there way to do it all in one, maybe with a mutate function?

Comment: Doesn't "normal reassignment" work? I'd think `dat$vec <- sprintf("%06d", dat$vec)` would work. I know nothing of your real data, please edit your original question and add the output from `dput(head(dat))` where `dat` is your frame. (See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for various discussions on how to include data and make the question _reproducible_.) Thanks!

Comment: thank you, yes i was able to get it to work using the following: vec <- sprintf("PV%06d", turnAL$`Masterlist code`)
turnAL$`Masterlist code` <- vec

Comment: Cool. What about cutting out `vec` and doing just `turnAL$\`Masterlist code\` <- sprintf("PV%06d", turnAL$\`Masterlist code\`)`?

Comment: Excellent!  thanks for streamlining